# "process component pubsub error: init timeout for component pubsub exceeded after 5s"

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka, microservices, publish-subscribe, dapr

I am using DAPR , Docker in my .net core microservice.
I have made following configuration in docker-compose.yml to run broker and dapr pubsub configuration.

PUBSUB.yml

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: pubsub
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: pubsub.kafka
  version: v1
  metadata:
      # Kafka broker connection setting
    - name: brokers
      value: local:9092
    - name: authRequired
      value: "false"
    - name: maxMessageBytes
      value: 1024
```

and Dockercompose.yml

```
  zookeeper:
     image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.1
     ports:
      - "2181:2181"
     environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
      - "9090:9090"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
```

My dapr car is not getting initialize in local environment , its throwing error as follows

image

error :

```
time="2021-04-12T07:05:26.9278616Z" level=info msg="starting Dapr Runtime -- version 1.0.0 -- commit 6314733" app_id=monitoringapi instance=43a8c7996e98 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.0.0

time="2021-04-12T07:05:26.9282174Z" level=info msg="log level set to: info" app_id=monitoringapi instance=43a8c7996e98 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.0.0

time="2021-04-12T07:05:26.9317538Z" level=info msg="metrics server started on :9090/" app_id=monitoringapi instance=43a8c7996e98 scope=dapr.metrics type=log ver=1.0.0

time="2021-04-12T07:05:26.9339347Z" level=info msg="loading default configuration" app_id=monitoringapi instance=43a8c7996e98 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.0.0

time="2021-04-12T07:05:26.9349457Z" level=info msg="standalone mode configured" app_id=monitoringapi instance=43a8c7996e98 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.0.0

time="2021-04-12T07:05:26.9350359Z" level=info msg="app id: monitoringapi" app_id=monitoringapi instance=43a8c7996e98 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.0.0

time="2021-04-12T07:05:26.9354469Z" level=info msg="mTLS is disabled. Skipping certificate request and tls validation" app_id=monitoringapi instance=43a8c7996e98 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.0.0

time="2021-04-12T07:05:26.9384313Z" level=info msg="local service entry announced: monitoringapi -> 172.28.0.11:37301" app_id=monitoringapi instance=43a8c7996e98 scope=dapr.contrib type=log ver=1.0.0

time="2021-04-12T07:05:26.9385462Z" level=info msg="Initialized name resolution to standalone" app_id=monitoringapi instance=43a8c7996e98 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.0.0

time="2021-04-12T07:05:32.3047616Z" level=fatal msg="process component pubsub error: init timeout for component pubsub exceeded after 5s" app_id=monitoringapi instance=43a8c7996e98 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.0.0
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Hi mate, I am having the same problem. Has this been resolved？ Thanks.

Comment: The title of the question says nothing about what is happening. Change it so that you have more chances of receiving an answer. It needs to be more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved following simple config has resolved this
[image]